# Why are folders in %USERPROFILE% all read-only?

Tags: windows-10, read-only

I was trying to edit a text file located in my user folder in Notepad++ then  realized I couldn't save it.

After checking it turns out that Windows set read-only attribute in every item in my user folder.

Fixing it was easy but I am still wondering **why did Windows did so** ?

Please note that compared to other answers I've found these aren't a copy from an old installation in which one should override ownership and so on; these were created by my current installation.

Comment: What folder exactly within your user profile were you trying to use?  You should have write access to most of the folders.

Comment: The folders and files in your own USER folder are readily available to you. Natively, Windows does not prevent this. Might you have done something? or used a different USER name ?

Comment: No I didn't, I am the only user on this PC. I was editing a file in `source/repos`, the place where Visual Studio projects are put by default. In turns out that many software will not honor the read-only flag but Notepad++ did.

Comment: Folder `C:\Users\USER\source\repos` is itself read-only. I suppose that Visual Studio sets this attribute on purpose, to force using it only as the only editor.

Comment: When I do `dir /ar` I can see every single folder being read-only. Actually I am thinking about something, do you think this could be coming from Acronis True Image or Bitdefender Total Security ? I have both of these products.

Comment: Read only on a folder is a/ not shown in the GUI b/ has no affect in the GUI c/ In a console prevents the folder being deleted.

Comment: The reason you didn’t have permissions is due to GIT not Windows.

Comment: What does git has to do with that and why would it have set attributes of all folders?

Answer (score 1):

If you've been subjected to the flawed Microsoft Windows Update [KB4532693](https://techdator.net/windows-10-update-microsoft-removed-the-kb4532693-update-after-several-complaints/), it may have created *[an additional user profile](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-kb4532693-update-bug-hides-user-data-loads-wrong-profile/)*. If you log in as that new user, perhaps "000" all your data will be unavailable unless you either:

- Log in a as Administrator.
- Revert from the bad update.

Since MS has reduced the QA staff, [users have become beta testers.](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/187407/microsoft-has-a-software-quality-problem)

Comment: I have checked whether I had it installed using methods in here https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-check-if-a-windows-update-kb-is-installed/ but it couldn't see it !